# getting user-defined math function in proper font in beamer

Tags: fonts, beamer

When I use beamer, things like `\sin`, `\cos`, etc. appear in the sans-serif font.  But if I say

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}
```

and then use `\lcm` inside a math formula, it appears in the cmr font.  How can I get it to appear in the sans-serif font like other math functions?

Comment: It doesn't happen to me; you should add the font loading part of your preamble.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{foo}{bar}

\[ \lcm = l\times c\times m \]

\end{frame}   
\end{document}
```

[image]